# UIEdgeInsets.init is Not working on Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, css, swift, textview

I am working on the ios project. I want to adjust the internal Margin value of text view 'UIEEdgeInsets.I tried to use 'init'. But it shows an error.

> Use of unresolved identifier 'bottom'

I have referred to the use of official documents and have not found the problem. What am I missing?

**Usage**

```swift
    @IBAction func NextButtonfuc(_ sender: Any) {
        if  agreeOneCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeThreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            allAgreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeTwoCheck.isSelected != true
        {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
            myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            myAlert.modalCustomAlert.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0) // get Error
            myAlert.text = "OK Thanks"
            self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

*************************Edit start *******************************************

I corrected the code by referring to the answer.

```swift
    @IBAction func NextButtonfuc(_ sender: Any) {
        if  agreeOneCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeThreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            allAgreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeTwoCheck.isSelected != true
        {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
            myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
            myAlert.modalCustomAlert.textContainerInset = insets //  Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
            myAlert.text = "OK Thanks"
            self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

> get error : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while
>   implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

*************************Edit end *******************************************

*************************Edit Second *******************************************

**ModalViewController**

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ModalViewController : UIViewController {

    var text: String?


    @IBOutlet weak var modalCustomAlert: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func okPress(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalCustomAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.modalCustomAlert.text = text
    }





    func changeViewFont() {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        if screenWidth < 375 {
            // iPhone 4inch and 3.5inch. Smaller than iPhone 8
            // Call change font
            modalCustomAlert.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

            okButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        }
        if screenHeight > 667 {

            modalCustomAlert.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

            okButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        }
    }


}
```

*************************Edit end *******************************************

Comment: Check if  `bottom` uses all latin letters. Also better use direct call like `UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Comment: Hi @ModoLtunzher  The reason why I added the decimal point is the type of value Float. You can tell by looking at the official documents. And the errors are the same.

Comment: @hongdevelop Please show `ModalViewController` code where you defined `modalCustomAlert`. It looks like `modalCustomAlert` or `textContainerInset` is `nil`.

Comment: @ModoLtunzher I added ModalViewController in my question

Comment: @hongdevelop nor `Int` neither `Float` is `CGFloat` thus it needs conversion. In your case you use number value directly, so it will be compiled as `CGFloat` in this place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by passing the value to the Controller class after thinking about it.

```swift
    @IBAction func NextButtonfuc(_ sender: Any) {
        if  agreeOneCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeThreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            allAgreeCheck.isSelected != true ||
            agreeTwoCheck.isSelected != true
        {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let myAlert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController") as! ModalViewController
            myAlert.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            myAlert.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 100.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
            myAlert.marginValue = insets 
            myAlert.text = "OK Thanks"
            self.present(myAlert, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

**ModalViewController**

```swift
    var text: String?
    var marginValue : UIEdgeInsets?
...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        modalCustomAlert.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.modalCustomAlert.text = text
        self.modalCustomAlert.textContainerInset = marginValue!
    }
```